# aws lambda: How to fix 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH"

Tags: selenium, aws-lambda, geckodriver

So I am trying to use firefox in aws lambda runtime Python3.6 I have added my dependencies using layers in this order: selenium3.14,  geckodriver25 and firefox 69 binary, to create my webdriver instance I am using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
path = '/tmp/'

def start_browser(url, headless=True):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    options = Options()
    if headless==True:
        options.headless = True
    fp.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xls, application/vnd.ms-excel")
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", path)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(
        options=options,
        executable_path="/opt/geckodriver",
        log_path="/tmp/geckodriver.log",
        firefox_profile=fp,
        firefox_binary="/opt/firefox/firefox"

    )
    browser.get(url)
    return browser
```

My function executes but I get this response when testing from aws console

```
{
  "message": "Your function executed unsuccessfully!",
  "event": "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. \n"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some info as to how you got Firefox running in Lambda? I've tried downloading [this firefox binary](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/39.0b7/linux-x86_64/en-US/) to a mounted EFS partition, but I get an error that the binary is not a binary when calling it as headless with the correct geckodriver version. @imlearingcode

Comment: Hi @Kile! Did you find the solution to the binary not being a binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change my path to lambda dependecies from `"/opt/my_dependency"` to `"/opt/python/my_dependency"`

Comment: Hi! @imlearningcode. Do you know where I can find geckodriver25 and firefox 69 binary files?. I'm facing trouble scraping with chrome and want to give Firefox a chance.